# In Django Forms, how to add a filter to a SelectedMultiple control?

Tags: django

I'm working with Django Forms. In my model, i have a ManyToMany relationship between class X and class Y and Django shows a very annoying MultipleChoice control to edit this relationship. I would like to add a filter so editing the X object the user can filter the Y objects by name while he writes the name to finally select them

Some idea about how to do this in Django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, a `ManyToManyField` in a Django `Model` will be represented by a `ModelMultipleChoiceField` in the `ModelForm`, which itself uses a `SelectMultiple` widget. This widget uses the default browser `<select multiple="multiple">` element, which results in your "annoying" multiple choice control.

So in order to replace it, you should override the `ModelMultipleChoiceField` in your form to pass it your own widget (which would subclass `SelectMultiple` and override the template used):

```
my_field = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Y.objects.all(), widget=MySelectMultiple)
```

However, many people have already done this kind of thing, so it's probably easier to use a package that has a nice multiple choice widget to your liking.

A very popular jquery module on the front-end is [select2](https://select2.org). If you want to use it, there are some django packages that already support it, popular ones are [django-autocomplete-light](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/) and [django-select2](https://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Thank you so much!